# Proof $P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap B^\complement \cap C^\complement ) - P(A \cap B \cap C)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The questions is from the Bertseka's book.

We have to prove for any events $A,B$ and $C$ that:
$P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap B^\complement \cap C^\complement ) - P(A \cap B \cap C)$

There is a hint, that we have to use $P(A) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} P(A \cap S_{i})$ where $S_{i}'s$ are a disjoint partion of the sample space $\Omega$.

Since $A,B$ and $C$ are arbitrary events, it is not said that they form a disjoint partition of the sample space.

My question is, how to form a disjoint partition of the sample space formally (with venn diagrams I can derivate everything)

I have tried to start with the following, but this leads to an dead end:

$P(A) = P(A \cap \Omega)$

$= P(A \cap (B \cup B^\complement))$

edit:
with the use of the following partion: $\Omega=\{B, C, B^\complement \cap C^\complement \setminus (B \cap C)\}$

$P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap (B^\complement \cap C^\complement \setminus(B \cap C)))$

$= P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap (B^\complement \cap C^\complement)) - P(A \cap B \cap C)$

$= P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap B^\complement \cap C^\complement) - P(A \cap B \cap C)$

Comment: Do the three events $ B, C, B^c\cap C^c-B\cap C$ form a disjoint partition?

Comment: thank you very much! I added the solution to the original post.

Answer (score 4):

$ A = \left(A \cap B \right) \cup \left(A  \cap B^\complement\right)$

$ A = \left(A \cap B \right) \cup \left(A  \cap B^\complement \cap C\right) \cup \left(A  \cap B^\complement \cap C^\complement\right)$

but 
$A \cap C = \left(A \cap C \cap B\right) \cup \left(A \cap C \cap B^\complement\right) \implies  \left(A \cap C\right) \setminus \left(A \cap C \cap B\right) =\left(A \cap C \cap B^\complement\right)$

Then 
$ A = \left(A \cap B \right) \cup \left(A \cap C\right) \setminus \left(A \cap C \cap B\right) \cup \left(A  \cap B^\complement \cap C^\complement\right)$

$\therefore P(A) = P\left(A \cap B \right) + P\left(A \cap C\right) - P\left(A \cap C \cap B\right) + P\left(A  \cap B^\complement \cap C^\complement\right)$